# Want to convert a dataframe of one column containing sentences in each column to string

Tags: pandas

*THis is the dataframe i am only posting here a part of it*

**dataframe = ['want to close my card', 'want to deactivate emi 44 card', 'want to deactivate 55 my bajaj emi card', 'want to deactivate 55 my emi card', 'want to discontinue my 77 bajaj finserv card', 'what is the process to cancel my emi card']**

*So how do i convert all of this into string values*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col':  ['want to close my card', 'want to deactivate emi 44 card', 'want to deactivate 55 my bajaj emi card', 'want to deactivate 55 my emi card', 'want to discontinue my 77 bajaj finserv card', 'what is the process to cancel my emi card']})
print(' '.join(df.col))
```

O/P:

```
'want to close my card want to deactivate emi 44 card want to deactivate 55 my bajaj emi card want to deactivate 55 my emi card want to discontinue my 77 bajaj finserv card what is the process to cancel my emi card'
```

If your col has list of strings,try this.

```
df.col.apply(lambda x: x.pop())
```

Comment: that is ..[''want to close my card', 'want to deactivate emi 44 card', 'want to deactivate 55 my bajaj emi card', 'want to deactivate 55 my emi card', 'want to discontinue my 77 bajaj ']

Comment: I ll tell you what is the actual problem i am trying to put this dataframe in countvectorizer and it says this error

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: please make your question clear. show your input and expected output.

Comment: @ParvezSureliya - take a look at updated answer. hope this is what you want.

Comment: i dont know how can i explain this

Comment: It's pretty simple, print(df) and expected output df. btw, can you check the updated answer .